# Single word for an idea which I have difficulty to describe in words

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an apt single word to describe the situation I am in right now:

I know a somewhat complex concept in maths, but I *cannot describe* it in plain english because I have difficulty to put those ideas into words - for example to communicate with others or to write them as answer in a test. I am not able to write a definition because the concept is hard for me to describe in words even though I have a vivid mental construct of it.

I came across *ineffable* and its synonyms, but that is not what I am looking for as we are not talking about any taboo subject.

edit:

I found the following example for ineffable or inexpressible, but those may not fit into the situation:

"the *ineffable* Hebrew name that gentiles write as Jehovah".

What I need:

I have an intuitive understanding of the concepts of *limits and differentiability*, but I cannot easily express or describe them in words. For me, those ideas are __________

Comment: I have edited the question. PS: Google was my guide for that definition and example

Comment: _Ineffable_ doesn't necessarily mean _taboo_, but it usually refers to something of high emotional impact. I don't know that there is a single word for what you want. I'd suggest _impossible to describe in words_.

Comment: Looking further, something similar to [Tacit knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tacit_knowledge)

Comment: 'inarticulable' nominally matches your idea, but I fear does not sound felicitous.

Comment: I can get my head around the possibility that a non-native Anglophone might truly understand something, yet be unable to express it in English. But as a general principle, I'd say that if someone can't express something in their own *native* language, they don't fully understand whatever it is anyway. (Either that, or they don't have the same understanding of the word ***understand*** as me! :)

Comment: how about things which someone knows how to use well, but cannot explain how he does it?

Answer (score 1):

**inchoate**

> Imperfectly formed or formulated : FORMLESS, INCOHERENT
> *misty, inchoate suspicions that all is not well with the nation* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inchoate)

> Just begun and so not fully formed or developed; rudimentary.
> [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/inchoate)

> ...they can use drawing techniques to create images that were still
> **inchoate** concepts in their minds before they got them down on paper. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Organizing_for_Change_profession/PeECT1f0SP8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=nchoate).
>
> "What are you going to write? Poetry?"
> "I will not choose my form
> until my soul is ready. My knowledge is vast but **inchoate**. At the
> moment, I am collecting experience. [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Boston_Adventure/Zhf-DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=my%20understanding%20was%20%22inchoate%22&pg=PA149&printsec=frontcover)

(*Incoherent* as a choice risks being understood as *lacking intelligibility* rather than *lacking cohesion.*)

Comment: Please note that we are not talking about any original idea (I wish that was the case), the situation is rather a personal difficulty to put a learned understanding in writing for communication.

Comment: the main para. of my question is edited to improve the clarity

Answer (score 1):

An adjective fitting the situation is **nebulous**:

> *nebulous* [adjective]
>
> ...
>
> (2) (of a concept) vague or ill-defined.

[[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/nebulous)]

One example of the use of "nebulous to me":

> - *He made many important and influential discoveries in calculus, ... The theory is still nebulous to me*

[[Salma Rodriguez; Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/aesthetic-beauty-mathematics-salma-rodriguez)]

Though the usual way of expressing the situation is "I find the concept of limits *hard to grasp*."

Comment: this is a useful answer in its own right, somewhat related to what I'm looking for. But the real question is about difficulty in expressing, not understanding..something like you cannot tell how you are able to play a backhand in tennis well.

Comment: 'Inexpressible' has the broad sense 'incapable of being put into words' but the havily default subsense involves the sense of awe, wonder (or anguish). ['Inarticulable'](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inarticulable) is included in Wiktionary, but is rare, and focuses on the subject matter rather than personal limitations. In a search for synonyms of 'inarticulate', the phrase 'unable to express oneself [on a certain subject]' is IMO the best way to say this.

Answer (score 0):

### Unfathomable

> not capable of being fathomed:
>
> a: IMMEASURABLE
>
> b: impossible to comprehend

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfathomable)

> I have an intuitive understanding of the concepts of limits and
> differentiability, but I cannot easily express or describe them in
> words. For me, those ideas are *unfathomable*.

Just as a sailor can pilot a boat over the Mariana Trench without knowing how deep it is, you can use these math concepts in an intuitive fashion, without necessarily understanding it as, say, Leibniz.

Comment: This means unable to understand/unable to be understood, not unable to express.